# React router go back to specific page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I am trying to make a a back button for my pages that when clicked returns you to the search page with the filter options you selected still there. I have this halfway to working as the following implementation:

```
function goBack(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  Router.back()
}

const RewindToSearch = () => {
  return (
    <a href="/" onClick={goBack}>
      <Back>
        <Arrow />
      </Back>    
    </a>
  )
}
```

This will return you to the search page with the filter options chosen. However the page the back button is on also allows for looking at photos, if i open photos then close and try to use the back button I am returned to photos. Is there a way for goBack to return me to search page with the filter options I have selected ?

Comment: Then instead add a direct `Link` to the Search page

Comment: When doing as a Link (<Link href="/search/">) I lose my filter options

Comment: But still going back means going back to the previous page right I recommend to keep it the way it is but still if you want that to happen you can render those conditionally  by creating a state which holds the data of the click

Comment: What react-router version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very elegant but might work:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back to Last Page</a>
```